# How do I read the Win32 WM_MOVE lParam x,y coordinates in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I am trying to read the lParam x and y coordinates from WM_MOVE win32 message and getting strange values. I need to extract them from the lParam IntPtr somehow.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632631(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks

Comment: It’s 2 16 bit values in a single 32 bit one.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Simon Mourier already posted (which covers a number of standard macros), this method returns a `Point()` from a `message.LParam`.

> [MSDN suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove) to use the `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM` macros
> (defined in `WindowsX.h`) to extract the coordinates, warning against
> the possible wrong results returned by the `LOWORD` and `HIWORD`
> macros (defined in `WinDef.h`), because those return unsigned
> integers.

These are the definitions of the suggested macros:

```
#define GET_X_LPARAM(lp)    ((int)(short)LOWORD(lp))
#define GET_Y_LPARAM(lp)    ((int)(short)HIWORD(lp))
```

What's important is that these values must be signed, since secondary monitors return negative values as coordinates.

```
public static Point PointFromLParam(IntPtr lParam)
{
    return new Point((int)(lParam) & 0xFFFF, ((int)(lParam) >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET Reference source is a gold mine. In an internal [System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods+Util class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,e1ab28ba69954959,references) you will find these helpers, that talk the same as WM_MOVE documentation (high-order word = HIWORD, low-order word = LOWORD, etc.)

```
public static int MAKELONG(int low, int high) {
    return (high << 16) | (low & 0xffff);
}

public static IntPtr MAKELPARAM(int low, int high) {
    return (IntPtr) ((high << 16) | (low & 0xffff));
}

public static int HIWORD(int n) {
    return (n >> 16) & 0xffff;
}

public static int HIWORD(IntPtr n) {
    return HIWORD( unchecked((int)(long)n) );
}

public static int LOWORD(int n) {
    return n & 0xffff;
}

public static int LOWORD(IntPtr n) {
    return LOWORD( unchecked((int)(long)n) );
}

public static int SignedHIWORD(IntPtr n) {
    return SignedHIWORD( unchecked((int)(long)n) );
}

public static int SignedLOWORD(IntPtr n) {
    return SignedLOWORD( unchecked((int)(long)n) );
}

public static int SignedHIWORD(int n) {
    int i = (int)(short)((n >> 16) & 0xffff);
    return i;
}

public static int SignedLOWORD(int n) {
    int i = (int)(short)(n & 0xFFFF);
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coordinates in Windows messages are often two signed 16-bit numbers packed into a 32-bit number.

Ideally you should extract these as signed numbers emulating the [`GET_X_LPARAM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632654(v=vs.85).aspx)/`GET_Y_LPARAM` macros:

```
IntPtr lparam = (IntPtr) 0xfffeffff; // -1 x -2 example coordinate
uint lparam32 = (uint) lparam.ToInt64(); // We want the bottom unsigned 32-bits
short x = (short) (((uint)lparam32) & 0xffff);
short y = (short) ((((uint)lparam32) >> 16) & 0xffff);  

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("coordinates: {0} x {1}", x, y));
```

In the case of `WM_MOVE` you could also extract them as unsigned numbers (`ushort`) since the client area will never be negative.

Comment: LPARAM is pointer sized. So it's an IntPtr not a uint. We'll, could be UIntPtr depending on how the pinvoke is declared but question says IntPtr.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Does not matter, coordinates in messages are never > 32-bit.

Comment: I know. But the asker starts with an IntPtr. And not a uint. So they need to get from one to the other.